# Encrypting ODBC DSN login password programmatically

Tags: c++, parameters, connection-string, sybase-asa

I am using file DSN for connecting to Sybase database. Login password is encrypted and is stored with `EncryptedPassword` keyword in the .dsn file. I have the **requirement** to change the database password and update the DSN accordingly.

I am using `SQLDriverConnect` to connect to the database and `SQLWriteFileDSN` to modify the .dsn file.

**Is there any way to encrypt the new  given password same way Sybase does(keyword or special tag or some thing?).?**

Some limitation:

1. I know its not recommended to store password/encrypted bassword in DSN, but I can not provide the password on the run to connect call. I have to use DSN(System/User/File DSN). File DSN over others is just because it doesn't show password in a .dsn file if not encrypted.
2. Driver using is Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0 from iAnywhere Solutions, inc. `DBODBC9.DLL`. I guess its the pretty old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `dbdsn` utility that is shipped with SQL Anywhere. If you use the `-pe` switch, the password you specify will be encrypted when the DSN is saved.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Graeme. I think dbdsn utility only creates system/user DSNs. I tried couple to combinations for file dsn, but didn't work.

Comment: Anyways, I can get encrypted password using this utility and put it in the fileDSN(that involves creation of DSN, reading value from registry and deletion of DSN). Is there any simpler way i can opt(using other tool or API)?

Comment: Rather than reading the value from the registry, you can use dbdsn -g to display the DSN and redirect that output to a file. I'm afraid there is no option in dbdsn to write a file DSN. I don't understand from the question why a File DSN is necessary over a user/system DSN.

Comment: though all DSN are almost same, it has been observed that file DSN gives little more security over other two. if user tries to decrypt the password through wizard, entry will be deleted from the file. I guess, hacker can still get the actual password with little effort, but we dont have any other option right now. Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi graeme, It seems that dbdsn.exe utility's -pe doesn't work as expected on Windows 7 OS. -pe switch works as a 'e' value for commonbuffersize keyword. I am calling dbdsn utility as follows,dbdsn.exe -y -ws "DSN_NAME" -pe -c "Driver=VAL;UID=dba;EngineName=comp_name;AutoStop=YES;Integrated=No;PWD=password;Debug=NO;DisableMultiRowFetch=NO;CommLinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{HOST=127.0.0.1;DoBroadcast=NONE};Compress=NO". On xp and 2003 OS it is working fine and encrypting the password.

Comment: I tried changing the compatibility mode of dbdsn to xp or 2003, but didn't help. Any input on this? Thanks..

Comment: It has nothing to do with the version of Windows. dbdsn in versions 9 and previous supported the -p switch to set the CommBufferSize parameter, while in version 10 and later, -p was removed and -pe was added. On the machine where -pe is working as I described, you must be using SA version 10 or later. BTW, you may get better response to your SQL Anywhere questions on sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com.